# How to compare 2 dataframes from XLSX with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, logic

I'm working with 2 Excel files that contains some common values but not in the same order.

Df1 :

| Siren | Categorie |
| --- | --- |
| 143890789 | GE |
| 284928492 | PME |
| 398938159 | ETI |
| 018583198 | PME |
| 385981983 | PME |

Df2 :

| Siret | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 284928492 000 | TPE |
| 143890789 245 | GE |
| 018583198 535 | PME |
| 398938159 513 | ETI |
| 385981983 555 | PME |

Result :

| Siren | Categorie | Siret | Type | Verify |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 284928492 | PME | 284928492 000 | TPE | False |
| 284928492 | GE | 143890789 245 | GE | True |
| 284928492 | PME | 018583198 535 | PME | True |
| 284928492 | ETI | 398938159 513 | ETI | True |
| 284928492 | PME | 385981983 555 | PME | True |

My main goal is to compare Siren and Categorie (together, like a group) with Siret and Type to see if the value from Siren & Categorie are the same than Siret & Type.
Example :

143890789:GE Df1

143890789:GE Df2

Df1 = Df2 so I will write in a new column "Verify" True or false or anything else.

First I need to remove the last 3 digits of Siret to get the same format that Siren, I tried to use a range but it just

Second I need to order them the same, but in the real table I have like few hundreds values so I can't do it manually, how can I do ?

Third I need to link Siren & Categorie and Siret & Type then check if value are the same from Siren and Siret

Fourth do sth when type & categorie are not the same.

How can I do that ? Thanks you !

Comment: You already have the algorithm, try it out now...

Comment: I can't find how to remove the 3 last digit... I tried to use df1['Siret'].loc(0:9) but it just show me the 9 first rows of my table

Comment: check str.split function